# Pgfplots' groupplots, automatic legend and axis name placement

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

So, I've been working on an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33737/pgfplots-put-plot-legend-on-the-outside-margin/240024#240024) and worked on adapting it to groupplots, i.e. placing automatically legend on the outside margin, axis ticks and labels on the inside I'm facing two issues with the mwe thereafter:

- How to cleverly turn on/off axis label according to the side ? A possible way is another use of \ifoddpage but it's rather not beautiful I think. I might have forgot something from the manual.
- How to use `trim axis group left/right` together with the legend placement proposed by Jake in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37568/colors-and-legend-in-groupplots-barplot) ? When triming axes, the legend is placed with the former positions, not exactly the expected results...

Here is the main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \input{groupplot}
  \caption{first figure}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[H]
  \input{groupplot}
  \caption{first figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here is the `groupplot.tex` figure:

```
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
  \def\yticksside{ edge right}
  \else
  \def\yticksside{ edge left}
  \fi

  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis group left,trim axis group right]
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style = {
          group size = 2 by 1,
          horizontal sep=0mm,
    yticklabels at=\yticksside,
        },
        width=0.5\columnwidth,
        ylabel={$y$label},
      ]

      \nextgroupplot[
        xlabel={$x$},
        legend to name=grouplegend,
    ylabel near ticks,
      ]
      \addplot coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) };
      \addlegendentry{Legend entry}

      \nextgroupplot[
        xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel near ticks,
      ]
      \addplot coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) };
    \end{groupplot}

  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
  \def\legendpos{group c1r1.south west}
  \def\legendanchor{north east}
  \else
  \def\legendpos{group c2r1.south east}
  \def\legendanchor{north west}
  \fi

  \node at (\legendpos) [anchor=\legendanchor]  {\ref{grouplegend}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```